# Basic Algebra Help

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

\begin{align}
x^2-2x+1 &= x^2-2x+1\\
(1-x)^2 &= (x-1)^2\\
\sqrt{(1-x)^2} &= \sqrt{(x-1)^2}\\
1-x &= x-1\\
1-x &= -1\cdot(1-x)\\
1 &= -1
\end{align}

I definitely did something wrong.

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$.

Answer (score 2):

$a^2 = b^2$ does not mean $a=b$. For example $1^2 = (-1)^2$ but that doesn't mean $1 = -1$. Instead, all you can conclude is that $|a| = |b|$, which means that $a=b$ or $a=-b$.

Comment: If I was integrating sqrt(x^2-2x+1) and wanted to factor to get rid of the square root which one would I change it to? and why?

Comment: You try both. Clearly $1-x = x - 1$ is not the correct one, so it must be that $1-x=-(x-1)$, which will obviously hold for all real $x$.

Comment: @JayLoz : $\sqrt{(x-1)^2} = |x-1| = \begin{cases} x-1 & \text{when }x\ge 1, \\ 1-x & \text{when } x<1.  \end{cases} \qquad $

Comment: @ZainPatel : $\quad \uparrow\quad$ You don't merely "try both".

Comment: @MichaelHardy $\int^{100}_{-100}\sqrt{(x^2-2x+1)} dx$ <br> <br>
you would break this up into 2 integrals? Using.. $\sqrt{(x-1)^2} = |x-1| = \begin{cases} x-1 & \text{when }x\ge 1, \\ 1-x & \text{when } x<1.  \end{cases} \qquad$

Comment: @JayLoz : Yes. $\displaystyle \int_{-100}^1 + \int_1^{100} \qquad $

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x^2-2x+1 &= x^2-2x+1\\
(1-x)^2 &= (x-1)^2\\
\sqrt{(1-x)^2} &= \sqrt{(x-1)^2}\\
\end{align}

OK, as square root is unambiguously defined as non-negative value.

---

**First** (very common) error is that from the last equation follows

\begin{align}
1-x &= x-1\\
\end{align}

That is not correct, as you may see from this example:

\begin{align}
4^2 &= (-4)^2\\
\end{align}

so

\begin{align}
\sqrt{4^2} &= \sqrt{(-4)^2}\\
\end{align}

in spite of

\begin{align}
4 \neq -4
\end{align}

(Remember, square root is a non-negative value, so right-hand side is incorrect.)

---

**Second**, also a common error is dividing both sides of an equation with the same number *without a consideration if it is not zero*:

\begin{align}
1-x &= -1\cdot(1-x)\\
1 &= -1
\end{align}

The correct method for solution of the equation

\begin{align}
1-x &= -1\cdot(1-x)\\
\end{align}

is put all members with $x$ to one side of the equal sign and others to the opposite one:

\begin{align}
-2x &= -2\\
 x &= 1\\
\end{align}

From this (single) solution you may immediately see why dividing both sides by $(1-x)$ was incorrect - we divided them by zero.